# Ensure a Row is unique on insert

Tags: sql-server-2012

SQL Server simple problem - ensure that only 1 batch is active at one time. Each batch has an assigned BatchID# - however that ID# might not be unique if a batch is re-run at some point. However, for a given ID# there should only ever be one "active" batch - that is only one batch with BatchComplete equal to NULL.

So the table I have is:

```
CREATE TABLE BatchTable (
     BatchNumber INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
     ,BatchID INT NOT NULL
     ,BatchStart DATETIME2(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
     ,BatchComplete DATETIME2(2) NULL
     ,BatchLastOperation DATETIME2(2) DEFAULT GETDATE()
     BatchState INT NOT NULL
);
```

Then I have a constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BatchTable]
ADD CONSTRAINT bt_OnlyOneBatchNumber UNIQUE (BatchID, BatchComplete)
GO
```

But last night this failed -- two inserts occurred in the same moment and both were inserted - chaos ensued.

I am guessing the problem was that `("20160619", NULL) != ("20160619", NULL)` and therefore the rows were seen as unique. So the solution would be to create a non-null "IsComplete" column rather than relying upon the existence of the datetime in BatchComplete column.

So my questions are:

1. Is my guess correct?
2. Is there a better way? Surely this kind of pattern has to be pretty common (I have done something similar before though I used triggers rather than a constraint).

The BatchState might work rather than IsCompete -- but the constraint would need to be for a given BatchID all *other* rows must have a BatchState greater or equal to 4. Not sure how to make that constraint.

Comment: Check transaction isolation level. Normally inserting ('20160619', NULL) twice  is impossible due to `UNIQUE (BatchID, BatchComplete)`. You can easily check it. This is just the point where MS SS contradicts ANSI standard which allows muliple NULLs.

Comment: So based upon your comment I went and tested and was able to insert multiple rows -- BUT THEN - I just went to ensure the constraint was in place and it WAS NOT. When I  tried to add it, it failed because of the test rows I just added. So the constraint works IF it is actually in the DB. Now the fun becomes explaining why it is not there!

Comment: @Serg's comment should be an answer. What nickdmax describes should never happen, if the constraint has been created.

Comment: Another option that achieves the same as the constraint but cares only for the NULL values is a `UNIQUE INDEX (BatchID) WHERE (BatchComplete IS NULL)`. It would use less space than the index that your UNIQUE constraint does. The only side effect is that it would allow two rows with same BatchID and same BatchComplete datetime (which should never happen anyway if no two batches with same batchID are active at the same time and the completion datetime is recorded correctly!)

Comment: Thank you, this has been a most enlightening question with great suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to SQL Server so I googled the syntax for generated columns, but there's probably syntax errors in here anyhow. The idea is to use a generated column that has a unique value (BatchNumber) whenever BatchComplete is not null, and a non-unique number (BatchId) otherwise:

```
CREATE TABLE BatchTable 
( BatchNumber INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY 
, BatchID INT NOT NULL
, BatchComplete DATETIME2(2) NULL
, Active AS (CASE WHEN BatchComplete IS NULL 
                  THEN BatchID 
                  ELSE BatchNumber 
             END) PERSISTED
, CONSTRAINT ONLY_ONE_ACTIVE_AT_ATIME UNIQUE ( BatchID, Active )
);
```

If BatchComplete IS NULL then UNIQUE (BatchId, BatchId) must hold, i.e only one Active batch at a time.

If BatchComplete IS NOT NULL then UNIQUE (BatchId, BatchNumber) must hold, but BatchNumber itself is unique, so this will always be true.

As mentioned I can't test this, but you might be able to use the idea one way or another.

Comment: Oh, I see now that (in @Serg comment) that SQL-server treats null as a value. Your constraint should therefor work, but I'll leave the answer anyhow since it may be of interest for similar situations in other DBMS.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I actually really like your solution and my add something like it to future improvements. I have never created a column with a CASE in it before.

Answer (score -4):

You can Use ajax request for checking and in codeigniter has built in function Is_Unique[databse.table_name]

Comment: Hi, Welcome to the site. I fail to see what this answer has to do with the question.